# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, object, properties, laravel-5.3

`ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object -- laravel 5.3`

I'm getting trouble in getting the data from foreign key . already make relation between 2 tables, but still error gave me this `Trying to get property of non-object`

Controller

```
   public function show($id){
        $activiter = Activiter::find($id);
        return view('activiter.show',compact('activiter'));
    }
```

show.blade.php

```
@foreach($activiter as $data) 
    @if($data->eleves)
      <td>
        {{ $data->eleves->nom }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ $data->eleves->prenom }}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{ $data->eleves->date_naissance }}
      </td>
    @endif 
@endforeach
```

Model

```
   public function eleves(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Eleve');
    }
```

Comment: Could you add the Activiter model?

Comment: At which line no. you are getting error.

Comment: Activiter model it added :(
@AmitGupta i get **error** especially when i called the method from model's activiter like this : $data->eleves in show.blade.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Activiter::find($id)` returns a Model object so you can't foreach it.

Your blade file should be as:

```
@foreach($activiter->eleves as $data) 
    <td>
      {{ $data->nom }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ $data->prenom }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ $data->date_naissance }}
    </td>
@endforeach
```

And you should use [`findOrFail()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) to confirm that data is fetched correctly as:

```
`$activiter = Activiter::findOrFail($id);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `->get()`.

`$activiter = Activiter::find($id)->get()`;

Comment: **Nothing changed**
but the message changed to 
" Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$type "